# Linux: command passed to tar in backticks is replaced on one system but not the other: what could cause that difference?

Tags: bash, tar

I am debugging a shell-script that works fine on one system but fails on another.
The script essentially unzips and untars archived log-files and then greps for a given substring in the contained log-files.

After some analysis and debugging I now found out that on one system an embedded `basename $TAR_FILENAME` command is properly executed (i.e. the command between the back-ticks is executed and the result replaces the part of the string between the back-ticks) while on the other system that replacement does NOT happen and instead the string `basename <filename-here>` (including the back-ticks) is inserted. This then of course derails the further processing of that string and the grep's don't work.

What could cause this? Can one enable/disable the back-tick feature in the bash?
I am not aware of any setting or switch that allows to toggle that feature on/off. Or is there?

Later addition:
This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern=$1
for f in *.tar.gz; do
     echo "$f:"
     tar -xzf "$f" --to-command 'echo "f:`basename $TAR_FILENAME` s:'"$pattern\""
done
```

On one system this yields lines like:
f:localhost_access_log.2021-07-29.txt s:pattern

On the second this yields lines like:
f:`basename ./localhost_access_log.2021-07-29.txt` s:pattern

Both systems are on SLES-11 (very old, indeed...).

Comment: have you tried using `$()` instead of backticks? for example: `test_var=$(echo "This is a test")`

Comment: Trivial question: are you _sure_ the script is the same on both systems? Sometimes, if you copy&paste using some editors, they try to be smart and change quotes to make them look pretty.

Comment: What are your systems ? Do you have an example (with shebang, first line, of your script) ?

Comment: @SimpleNiko I shortly tried but in the actual script (this here is just a condensed snippet) is a complicated nesting of single and double quotes and when I tried to relace this with $(...) the output was completely off. So - if possible - I would prefer to stick to the back-ticks.

Comment: @cornuz yes: they are really the same - checked with a hex-editor!

Comment: @Arnaud Valmary I added the script (or rather my isolated snippet which shows different output on the two systems).

Comment: Do you have the same `tar` version on both systems?

Comment: forgetting the local script(s) for the moment ... if you cut-n-paste the code you've provied (above) to a terminal/command line in each host ... do you get different output?

Comment: @SimpleNiko I ran your test_vcar=  snippet, once with backticks and once with $(...) and the output was identical. Odd!

Comment: @tripleee Not quite: `tar --version` yields `tar (GNU tar) 1.26` on the system where things work and `tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1` on the system where things fail.

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes - with a copy paste from the same copy-buffer into two different ssh-windows (one system each) the output differs exactly as described above. One echos with the basename executed, the other WITH the string in backticks.

Comment: There are minor syntactic differences between backticks and the modern `$(...)` command substitution syntax but for the most part the latter is more comfortable to work with. If you have complex quoting, you will need to change more than just the backticks.

Comment: Works for me on Debian Buster with GNU tar 1.30 so it's probably more than the version difference ... unless SLES have their own patches to actively disable this facility.

Comment: I emitted and compared tar's help: the working one at the very end says:
`*This* tar defaults to:
--format=gnu -f- -b20 --quoting-style=escape --rmt-command=/usr/libexec/rmt
--rsh-command=/usr/bin/rsh`, the non-working one says: `*This* tar defaults to:
--format=posix -f- -b20 --quoting-style=escape --rmt-command=/usr/lib/rmt
--rsh-command=/usr/bin/rsh`. The 'posix' make me think, that this may be the reason. AFAIK the POSIX-shell does not support this back-tick feature. Any idea anyone where this could be configured?

Comment: @markp-fuso Odd - both systems say:  # x=/a/b/cde.txt ; echo \`basename $x\` ; echo $(basename $x)
cde.txt
cde.txt  (unfortunately the line breaks get messed up in these comments but you'll get the idea).

Comment: actually, the fact that you're getting the same output at the command line would tend to eliminate `bash` and `<backticks>` in general and also point at `tar` as being the issue (possibly related to the `format=gnu` vs `format=posix`  mentioned earlier); short of installing a different version of `tar` I'd look at replacing backticks with `$(...)`; keeping in mind earlier comments re: nested quotes/ticks/etc... pull the `basename` out to a variable and pass variable to `tar`, eg: `basen=$(basename $TAR_FILENAME)` (or use backtickers here) and then `tar ... "f:${basen} s:...`

Comment: For what it's worth, the POSIX shell handles backticks just fine, like any Bourne shell, including the original Bourne shell which introduced this syntax (at least in its current form; maybe the Thompson shell had a similar construct?)

Comment: @mmo : I think you have a problem of quotes/back-quotes balancing. Try this : `tar -xzf "$f" --to-command 'echo "$(basename $TAR_FILENAME) s:"'"$pattern"`

Comment: Thanks and cheers to all for contributing and your valuable suggestions! I appreciate you efforts. Meanwhile I got my script working - see the accepted answer below and my comments underneath it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tar 1.26 passed the command to a shell ([source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/system.c?id=aea443b9e8ed8f84a3b7c246330aa194f6b7e1ef#n725)):

```
  argv[0] = "/bin/sh";
  argv[1] = "-c";
  argv[2] = to_command_option;
  argv[3] = NULL;

  priv_set_restore_linkdir ();
  execv ("/bin/sh", argv);
```

tar 1.27 changed this to skip the shell as part of another fix ([source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/system.c?id=49f3145092b00de0b21bd0b751b6caaa57db4fc4#n32)):

```
  if (wordsplit (cmd, &ws, (WRDSF_DEFFLAGS | WRDSF_ENV) & ~WRDSF_NOVAR))
    FATAL_ERROR ((0, 0, _("cannot split string '%s': %s"),
          cmd, wordsplit_strerror (&ws)));
  execvp (ws.ws_wordv[0], ws.ws_wordv);
```

Since the shell is responsible for handling backticks, they will be interpreted in 1.26 but not 1.27.1.

The behavior was [changed back](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/system.c?id=61cd3fd26855d40ee3a6491b2aa3611cd2aae46c#n28) for tar 1.29.

Comment: THAT of course explains the difference! Thanks a lot for digging that out and explaining it! So, no use in trying to fix or circumvent this somehow. Rather I'll try to dig up a new (or older) executable. Unfortunately this OS is so old that the download site is gone and no automatic installations or updates are possible anymore. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't look closely at how this splitting function works, but you could probably work around it by passing in `sh -c '...'`

Comment: @that_other_guy That's exactly how I meanwhile resolved the issue. Instead of having the command line directly following the `--to-command` option it now calls a shell script that contains the command to be executed. To spare me the hassle having to handle TWO scripts now I simply placed both parts into one file and if the first argument is a "magic word" then scripts acts as the second script, if not it behaves like the original first script.